# AnchorError caused by account: program_data. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

Running `anchor test` for the `bpf-upgrade-state` example program while on localnet results in the following error

```
Error: AnchorError caused by account: program_data. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.
```

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/bpf-upgradeable-state/programs/bpf-upgradeable-state/src/lib.rs

Error due to trying to use this address in the test

```
const programDataAddress = findProgramAddressSync(
    [program.programId.toBytes()],
    new anchor.web3.PublicKey("BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111")
  )[0];
```

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/bpf-upgradeable-state/tests/bpf-upgradable-state.ts#L15

`anchor test` works fine if on devnet though

The test runs on localnet if I complete the following steps as a workaround:

- run `solana-test-validator`
- then `anchor deploy`
- then `anchor run test`

Found these that seem related:

- https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/22694
- https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/22950

Could anyone explain why directly running `anchor test` for this example does not work on localnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you just run `anchor test` against a local network, it will start a new test validator using the `--bpf-program` argument with `solana-test-validator`, which defaults to the non-upgradeable loader.

If you want to change this behavior, you literally just need to change this line: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/00ba78bd2d2c3a40d99bb697a5d8bfbac4f62e70/validator/src/bin/solana-test-validator.rs#L210

to:

```
solana_sdk::bpf_loader_upgradeable::id()
```

Please feel free to put in a PR for this! Since the non-upgradeable loader is mostly unusable, this change makes a lot of sense.

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/29051